# live traffic information for android

Tags: android, api, rss, feed, traffic

I would like to know if there exists any live traffic rss feeds or apis for sweden that could be used offline? Like we have a local xml and everytime we go online the xml file updates.

Comment: ah sorry for not being accurate :P but for sweden?

Comment: The better questions you make, the better answers you get. @Pete seems to have provided a useful link already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply by using google I found this site: http://www.trafiklab.se/
A number of the API's support XML and JSON format to download the data.